# lte not working with timestamp

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to count documents in collection in date range. Here is my query:

```
$qb
        ->field('timestamp')->lte($dateRange['to'])
        ->field('timestamp')->gte($dateRange['from'])
        ->count()
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

$dateRange's elements are `DateTime` objects with valid (I've tested it) dates. Mongo collection has documents which I'm querying. Experimenting exposed that problem is in `lte` method - when I use only gte all works fine. Also tested `range()` method - it's not working too. Any ideas?

Query genereted by doctrine looks like:

```
{"count":true,"query":{"timestamp":{"$lte":{"sec":1413380708,"usec":0},"$gte":{"sec":1413380108,"usec":0}}},"limit":0,"skip":0,"db":"test","collection":"activity_log"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else will have such problem, I'll post an answer that worked for me. The problem was that I had field `timestamp` in db of type `Timestamp`, but was passing `\DateTime` objects to doctrine methods. So it seems that internally doctrine casts types wrong. And here is what I've done:

```
$qb
        ->field('timestamp')->range(
            new \MongoTimestamp($from->getTimestamp()),
            new \MongoTimestamp($to->getTimestamp()))
```